# How to identify dollar notes using android camera interface

Tags: android

I need to **identify dollar currency notes by using android camera** interface and need to crop that dollar note area inside the android mobile.
how should overcome with this problem.

Comment: This is kind of a REALLY BIG problem that is unlikely to be answerable in a Stack Overflow question, aside from perhaps pointing to an image-recognition API such as TinEye.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be using a **computer vision** library, such as **[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)**. It's written in C++, but has bindings for Java, and [even an Android version](http://opencv.alekcac.webfactional.com/android.html).

However, we're talking about a rather large and complex field. It's not an easy task, seeing as computer vision is still one of the largest open fields of computer science today. [The Wikipedia article should give you a nice overview of all the sub-areas of computer vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision).

You should see [this question (**How to recognizing money bills in Images?**)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172031/how-to-recognizing-money-bills-in-images), as it's quite similar to what you need, and there's already a really good answer with a nice code snippet written in python. I'm sure you can port it to Java or C++, and have a working starting point.

Comment: at-least can you tell me what are the steps i should follow in this case. if i use open cv.

Comment: You should first get comfortable with openCV on Android. Just get it to work and do some simple edge detection on whatever it sees through the phone camera. After you're done with that, try implementing the snippet of code from the question I linked you to. Hope this helps!